# How can I create a new script in R which is installed in Linux environment?

Tags: linux, r

How can I create a new script in R which is installed in Linux environment?

I get used to the R-GUI interface in Windows environment. I feel it's more convenient to create a new script in GUI and execute my codes line by line or treat them as a whole.

But I'm trying to use R in Linux system. I don't know how to create a new script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R scripts are just plain text files, no magic involved, so you can create it with any text editor of your liking.

If you want a proper R GUI you may want to check out [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/).